# Disable detaching of Parts in application based on e4

Tags: eclipse, e4

In my application I need to support DnD of parts within main window, but I want to disable detaching for all parts. In     `IPresentationEngine`     I didn't find any tags about detaching...Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any support for this in the standard DnD addon.

Detach drop is handled by the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DetachedDropAgent` class but it doesn't test any flags.

So I think the only way to do this is to write your own Dnd addon. You could copy must of the existing DnDAddon code.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful for me. I'll stop searching and begin to work in this way. Thank you.

Comment: In the continuation of the topic. I found a bug report [Bug 357289](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357289). And I suggested my decision: add the tag "NoDetach" by analogy with "NoMove". And add its check in  `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DetachedDropAgent.canDrop() `. I put this fix on [Gerrit](https://git.eclipse.org/r/113462). I don't know what I need to do to put this fix in next releases...